# How to delete non empty s3 bucket with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want to delete my non empty s3 bucket created with terraform. I used force_destroy=true option as well but still i get

```
BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty
status code: 409, request id: xxxx, host id: xxxxxxx
```

also the bucket was created with force_destroy option:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "pipelineartifactstore" {
  bucket = "${var.prefix}-${var.namespace}-${var.stage}-pipeline-artifactstore"
  acl    = "private"
  force_destroy = true
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
  tags = var.default_tags
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your correct code for the bucket? The code is correct and it works with either version and non-version buckets. Maybe you have some bucket policies set which prohibit deleting some objects?

Comment: I've created a bucket with the code provided, pushed some files into it, tested it with both with and without versioning - I was able to destroy it every time. I tried with lifecycle prevent_destroy = true but the message is different in TF14.

Comment: i was using it on some different resource but it works now :D
Thanks @Marcin

Answer (score 24):

There is a `force_destroy` option for buckets that can be set. When the value is `true` it will remove all items in the bucket and then remove the bucket too.

Once set, you'll be able to remove the resource and then run `terraform apply` and the bucket will be removed, no need for any additional CLI steps.

[Documentation Link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#force_destroy)

Comment: @gastrodon I think in fairness I misread the question. OP states he's already used force_destroy and is still having issues... I decided to leave the answer up just in case other people ended up on this page and made the same reading mistake as me, sounds like it might have helped at least one person so glad I did leave it up!

Comment: "Once set, you'll be able to remove the resource and then run terraform apply and the bucket will be removed, no need for any additional CLI steps." Add `force_destroy: true`, `terraform apply` and the bucket will be removed? That's not so. You need `terraform destroy` to delete the bucket and other resources.

Comment: @x-yuri `terraform destroy` is the same as `terraform apply -destroy`

Answer (score 13):

Some objects may be added before enable encryption or versioning so try to empty the bucket with AWS cli:

```sh
aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name --recursive
```

Then run Terraform apply again.

Since this is for Codepipeline I suppose.

Comment: +1 despite being a manual fix (not useful in automation), it has come in handy: eg if terraform destroy has already removed most of the stack, you only have too choices: run the command from this answer, or add the force_destroy flag and run `terraform apply --target <s3_resource_path>` which will only work if your bucket does not depend on other already-destroyed items in your state).

Comment: Note I had to add / to the end of the bucket name

Answer (score 9):

The best option here is to follow these steps:

1. Add `force_destroy = true` to your S3 configuration
2. Apply terraform code with `terraform apply`
3. Then `terraform destroy`. Even if you have data there, it will be removed and then the bucket removed too.